# Is there a way to package a simple Python project and have it perform installation over the internet

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I would like to know if there's a way to package a simple Python project and have it perform installation over the internet, just like when you install a module with `pip`.

Comment: Sure it is possible, but it is not a one-liner. StackOverflow is not a coding service. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am not asking for code, I asked if there's a way to do it.

Comment: Python is Turing-complete and can make system calls, so it is possible to do anything with it. Your question is not that clear. Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Sure there is. This is how all the 3rd party packages we are all using did.
The formal pypa explain how to do it [here](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/).

Basically you need to package your project to a wheel file and upload it to the pypi repository. To do this you need to declare (mainly in setup.py), what is your package name, version, which sub-packages you want to pack to the wheel etc..

Comment: I am not trying to do it that way. Let's say in order to use this Python project you need an activation key, if the activation key is correct it starts downloading project files.

Comment: you need to add more context. Is it another program that trying to install? please elaborate what you really need by describing a use case

Comment: OK. I made a Python project that when downloaded and opened you need to enter an activation key to activate it. If you enter the a correct activation key the program downloads additional files in order for to function. Just like Chrome when used to be downloaded and installed over the internet but with activation.

Comment: now it is more clear. you can put your packaged project wheel inside a private repository or even git repository (https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-from-vcs) with secret credential that is know to your main program.

Comment: Also, bear in mind, that there is no easy/standard way to install during running and use as if it was installed when the python was loaded. You can start a new python process, though.

Answer (score 0):

If your packages are required for a particular project, it is straightforward to contain them in the Git repository. You can put them in the directory named wheelhouse, which comes from the name of the previous default directory created by pip wheel.
If you put the private package foo in the wheelhouse, you can install as follows:

```
pip install foo -f wheelhouse
```